# cannot install grails 2.5 local plugin( zip file)

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

- I am trying to install jackson plugin :

https://codeload.github.com/sjhorn/grails-jackson/zip/master

- Its not attached to maven central, but i cant seem to successfully install it under grails 2.5 . I've tried :

  - putting the zip in lib folder .
  - using install-plugin .
  - renaming the package to grails-jackson .
  - using grails.plugin.location."grails-jackson" = "../grails-jackson"  .

My Build.config

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.8
grails.project.source.level = 1.8
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"


grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 512, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 512, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 512, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 512, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
         runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
 /*       compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.0-rc3'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.0-rc3'*/
        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55.2"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.8'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:2.1.5"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        compile ":hibernate4:4.3.8.1"//":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" //":hibernate:3.6.10.18" //
        compile ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

        runtime ":grails-jackson-master:0.1"
        //grails.plugin.location."grails-jackson" = "../grails-jackson"

        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from

```
        //grails.plugin.location."grails-jackson" = "../grails-jackson"

        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
    }
}
```

to

```
        //
        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
    }
}
grails.plugin.location."grails-jackson" = "../grails-jackson"
```

Comment: where should i put the zip & what should be the zip name?

Comment: I put it on the project folder & unzipped it ,and now it's linked SUCCESSFULLY.. thanks.

Comment: It is not working after Grails 2.3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810231/run-local-plugin-in-grails-2-3-x/21810632 seems to suggest same thing as this